# Affecting a UINavigationBar's Back Button Method (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar, back-button

I have a table view that pushes to a detail view controller. From the detail view controller, when I press the 'back' button, I'd like an integer value to change. How do I edit the navigation bar back button's action programatically. The back button is automatically placed in my app because I'm using a table view so I didn't actually create the button, so I don't know how to affect it's method.

To be clear, I still want the back button to go back to the original view, but simultaneously change an integer's value. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out an easy fix to this. I simply unchecked 'Shows Navigation Bar' in the Interface Builder for the UINavigationController that the Table View was contained in. Then I used a UINavigationBar to replicate the look (but be able to add and delete buttons as I pleased).

After that I just created IBAction's that I connected to the buttons and could control an integer value from there.

(P.S. The only problem with this is that there is no 'Back' button left pointing arrow shape in the XCode interface builder as many of you know. There are solutions around this that are pretty easily found if you search).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks PengOne to point me to this direction. 
Add the `UINavigationBarDelegate` in the header file and use this in the `.m` file:

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem     *)item
{
  //insert your back button handling logic here
  // let the pop happen
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Actually this method belongs to <UINavigationBarDelegate>

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `UINavigationController`, then `UINavigationBarDelegate` is the delegate class and it implements `-navigationBar:shouldPopItem`. You can put the action you want to trigger in that method, e.g. incrementing or decrementing a counter.

Comment: It's actually a UIViewController that's being used as the DetailViewController. The navigation bar that is displayed on the screen is the one that automatically appears when you push a detail view in from a TableViewController (am I making sense?). I don't know how to affect that navigation bar that automatically pops up from the table view...

Comment: @MxmastaMills There is a UINavigationController at work if you're using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController];` or similar code. Try overriding this method and see what happens.

Comment: Do I need to change the Detail View Controller to a UINavigationController in order to? Right now it's a UIViewController (even though that method you just mentioned is indeed being called)...

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing viewDidDisappear, which should be called as the detail view controller's view goes out of view.

Comment: The detail view controller actually goes forward and backward (to a 2nd detail view controller and back to the table view controller as well). So the viewDidDisappear wouldn't work in this case for me since it would change the value of the integer if they decided to click forward to the 2nd view controller. I only want the integer to change when it goes back. Does that make sense?